# Modify Numbers to Letters in VBA so the words not starts with "one"

Tags: excel, vba

My issue is that I want to modify the VBA code of converting numbers to words so I don't want the words to start with "one" for now it's not clear for you let me make it more clear for you:

Current VBA result:

```
100  One Hundred
1000 One Thousand
```

Desired VBA result:

```
100  Hundred
1000 Thousand
4000 four thousand
5466 five thousand four hundred sixty six
```

Reason: because I want to convert it to Turkish language and in Turkish language it's wrong to say One Hundred "Bir Yüz" the correct in Turkish language is Hundred "Yüz".

So how to perform that I am not that expert person in VBA and I need your help.

Below is the VBA Code:

```
Function NumberstoWords(ByVal pNumber)
    'Updateby20140220
    Dim Dollars
    arr = Array("", "", " Thousand ", " Million ", " Billion ", " Trillion ")
    pNumber = Trim(Str(pNumber))
    xDecimal = InStr(pNumber, ".")
    If xDecimal > 0 Then
        pNumber = Trim(Left(pNumber, xDecimal - 1))
    End If

    xIndex = 1
    Do While pNumber <> ""
        xHundred = ""
        xValue = Right(pNumber, 3)
        If Val(xValue) <> 0 Then
            xValue = Right("000" & xValue, 3)
            If Mid(xValue, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
                xHundred = GetDigit(Mid(xValue, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "
            End If
            If Mid(xValue, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
                xHundred = xHundred & GetTens(Mid(xValue, 2))
            Else
                xHundred = xHundred & GetDigit(Mid(xValue, 3))
            End If
        End If
        If xHundred <> "" Then
            Dollars = xHundred & arr(xIndex) & Dollars
        End If
        If Len(pNumber) > 3 Then
            pNumber = Left(pNumber, Len(pNumber) - 3)
        Else
            pNumber = ""
        End If
        xIndex = xIndex + 1
    Loop
    NumberstoWords = Dollars
End Function

Function GetTens(pTens)
    Dim Result As String
    Result = ""
    If Val(Left(pTens, 1)) = 1 Then
        Select Case Val(pTens)
        Case 10: Result = "Ten"
        Case 11: Result = "Eleven"
        Case 12: Result = "Twelve"
        Case 13: Result = "Thirteen"
        Case 14: Result = "Fourteen"
        Case 15: Result = "Fifteen"
        Case 16: Result = "Sixteen"
        Case 17: Result = "Seventeen"
        Case 18: Result = "Eighteen"
        Case 19: Result = "Nineteen"
        Case Else
        End Select
    Else
        Select Case Val(Left(pTens, 1))
        Case 2: Result = "Twenty "
        Case 3: Result = "Thirty "
        Case 4: Result = "Forty "
        Case 5: Result = "Fifty "
        Case 6: Result = "Sixty "
        Case 7: Result = "Seventy "
        Case 8: Result = "Eighty "
        Case 9: Result = "Ninety "
        Case Else
        End Select
        Result = Result & GetDigit(Right(pTens, 1))
    End If
    GetTens = Result
End Function

Function GetDigit(pDigit)
    Select Case Val(pDigit)
    Case 1: GetDigit = "One"
    Case 2: GetDigit = "Two"
    Case 3: GetDigit = "Three"
    Case 4: GetDigit = "Four"
    Case 5: GetDigit = "Five"
    Case 6: GetDigit = "Six"
    Case 7: GetDigit = "Seven"
    Case 8: GetDigit = "Eight"
    Case 9: GetDigit = "Nine"
    Case Else: GetDigit = ""
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Can't you just delete or comment out `Case 1: GetDigit = "One"` ?

Comment: If I do the result will be:
1 -> 0
1000 -> 0
10000 -> 0
100000... -> 0
so all the results will be 0 except 100 because I think there's a line in the code defining it individually

Comment: OK, then leave it in and modify to `Case 1: GetDigit = ""`

Comment: same result it still comes back with 0's

Comment: Minor query:  What would your expected output for **1100** be?  "Thousand Hundred" or "Thousand One Hundred"?

Comment: it's thousand one hundred but I want "Thousand Hundred" which is in Turkish "Bin Yüz" because if I say "Bin bir yüz" it's totally wrong in Turkish language btw bir = one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
Dollars = xHundred & arr(xIndex) & Dollars
```

to

```
Dollars = IIf(xHundred <> "One" Or arr(xIndex) = "", Replace(xHundred, "One ", "") & arr(xIndex), Trim(arr(xIndex)) & " ") & Dollars
```

For explaining, I will replace spaces (" ") with underscore ("_") for clarity:

- If `xHundred` is "One" **and** we are working on "_Thousand_" or "_Million_" (and so on) then it will add "Thousand_" or "Million_" instead.
- Otherwise, it will replace "One_" with nothing ("") and add the "_Thousand_" or "_Million_" to the end.
- This will change "One_Hundred_Seven" to "Hundred_Seven", but leave "Seven_Hundred_One" unchanged.

Comment: Return Error it's not allowing me to complete saving

Comment: @Volcano Sorry - I had forgotten the third argument (`, ""`) from the `Replace` function.  Now updated

Answer (score 4):

Add this at the end of the function *NumberstoWords()*:

```
If LCase(Left(NumberstoWords, 3)) = "one" And (Len(NumberstoWords) > Len("One")) Then
    NumberstoWords = Trim(Right(NumberstoWords, Len(NumberstoWords) - Len("One")))
End If
```

It checks first 3 characters for the word "one" and it makes sure it is not the word "one" itself. This is what it produces, consider adding another rule to avoid `150`:

```
?NumberstoWords(150)
Hundred Fifty
?NumberstoWords(1)
One
?NumberstoWords(100)
Hundred
?NumberstoWords(91)
Ninety One
?NumberstoWords(5466)
Five Thousand Four Hundred Sixty Six
```

Comment: it's amazing but another problem popped up the number 5466 -> Five Thousand Hundred Sixty Six    four hundred is missing I want to apply this case only if the hundred or thousand starts with "One" but if something else no keep insert them

Comment: @Volcano - this is the curse when working with insufficient specs.

Comment: tell me what you need to know and I will tell you actually I got this code from https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1446-excel-convert-change-numbers-to-words.html so I am not the writer of this code I am just trying to modify it, in the way which fits my needs

Comment: @Volcano - are you sure that `four hundred` is missing? I get it.

Comment: Yes man do you want me to give you a screenshot of that? 5466 still result Five Thousand Hundred Sixty Six I tried the code after you edit the code but still same problem

Comment: @Volcano - I gave you a copy-paste in the answer, it is the same as a screenshot. Are you sure you put the 3 lines exactly before the `End Function` of `NumberstoWords()`?

Comment: @Viyata yes I am sure bro
`NumberstoWords = Dollars
If LCase(Left(NumberstoWords, 3)) = "one" And (Len(NumberstoWords) > Len("One")) Then
    NumberstoWords = Trim(Right(NumberstoWords, Len(NumberstoWords) - Len("One")))
End If
End Function`

Comment: @Volcano - Can you create a new excel, copy the code from the question and add that piece once again to the end? You have probably deleted some of the lines from the original code.

Comment: alright I am going to do that again on a new excel file and I will comeback with the feedback thank you

Comment: @Volcano - you are welcome. If it bothered me I would not have answered :)

Comment: I found out another problem with the thousands for example `1100 -> One Thousand One Hundred` but I want  `1100 -> One Thousand Hundred` same issue with 4150, when the number is big and contain 100 - 199 the problem popped again I saw you typed that we maybe need extra condition to solve this problem can you help me with it?

Comment: @Volcano - there are plenty of ways to do it. The best one is to rewrite the whole code yourself, you would learn a lot from it (not kidding). Then you can even upgrade it and adjust it the way you want it. The easiest one for you is to add `Trim(Replace(NumberstoWords," one ", " ",compare:=vbTextCompare))` at the end of the code.

Comment: alright thank you, I am just disappointed from people whom vote down actually no body starts expert everybody was beginner and needed help from others btw nothing to say anymore" You people try to be Humble" Thanks.